# Entropy value of 6.46 on .dll file

Tags: c++

My question is concerning entropy, I read the description that Niyaz put posted several times.  I may still not be totally grasping the concept so I'll ask my question.  I have a .dll file I ran a couple tests on and one of the results was an Entropy value of 6.46 (Not Packed).  I'm Having a hard time figuring out exactly what that means, I understand the Not Packed part but the value of 6.46 I do not as I have not seen any scale for the values of Entropy. I'm probably not thinking about this correctly and I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks...

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question but rather an information theory question.

Comment: Yeah, but it also may concern entropy-based compression algorithms. Attempting to run the entropy calculation on a DLL file would prove that ;)

Comment: +1 for interesting question, no matter where it belongs.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, entropy is probably being measured in bits of entropy per byte of data. 8 is completely random, 0 is completely predictable.

In practical terms, this means that your DLL file can probably be compressed to about 80% (6.46 / 8) of its initial size.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of entropy is:

[image: Entropy]

Where:

- `a` denotes every possible character in a file and
- `P(A)` - probability of this char (equal to count of its occurrences divided by file size)

The base of logarithm defines unit of entropy. If it is equal to 2, entropy is measured in bits.

Entropy is a measure of uncertainty. Imagine a file consisting of the same letters. Then P(a) = 1 (as there is only one character) and entropy equals to:

[image: Entropy equal to 0]

Entropy of 0 bits means: no uncertainty, full predictability. On the other hand, imagine a file with each character different. There are 256 values of P, each equal to 1/256. Entropy then equals to:

[image: Entropy equal to 8]

Entropy of 8 bits means: full uncertainty, no predictability.

Entropy is correlated to compression ratio of entropy-based algorithms. As duskwuff said, entropy of 6.46 bits means, that the file may be compressed by entropy-based algorithms roughly to 4/5 of its original size.